# How to changing port on stellarterm?

Tags: stellar-core

I installed Stellar term on my own server
but the default port is 3001 and i want to change that, How can i change the ports in my own Stellar term?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `gulpfile.js`, and add a `port: xxxx` line inside the `browserSync` section.

You should note that this is really only for development, and for production purposes you should run `npm run production` and host the static files on your server instead.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work